# Binding value to style

Tags: angular

I'm trying to bind a color property from my class (acquired by attribute binding) to set the `background-color` of my `div`.

```js
import {Component, Template} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'circle',
  bind:{
    "color":"color"
  }
})
@Template({
  url: System.baseURL + "/components/circle/template.html",
})
export class Circle {
    constructor(){

    }

    changeBackground():string{
        return "background-color:" + this.color + ";";
    }
}
```

**My template:**

```html
<style>
    .circle{
        width:50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
</style>
<div class="circle" [style]="changeBackground()">
    <content></content>
</div>
```

The usage of this component:

```html
<circle color="teal"></circle>
```

My binding is not working, but doesn't throw any exceptions either.

If I would put `{{changeBackground()}}` somewhere in the template, that does return the correct string.

So why is the style binding not working?

Also, how would I watch the changes to the color property inside the `Circle` class? What is the replacement for

```js
$scope.$watch("color", function(a,b,){});
```

in Angular 2?

Answer (score 127):

Turns out the binding of style to a string doesn't work.
The solution would be to bind the background of the style.

```html
 <div class="circle" [style.background]="color">
```

Comment: you missed the quote as of https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/

```<div class="circle" [style.background]="'color'">```

Comment: For the sake of clarity: `color` in this case is a property on your component that contains the value you want to use. If you're using quotes that *is* the value you want to use. `color` isn't a valid CSS color. It would need to be something like `[style.background] = "'#f3f3f3'"`.

Answer (score 49):

As of now (Jan 2017 / Angular > 2.0) you can use the following:

```js
changeBackground(): any {
    return { 'background-color': this.color };
}
```

and

```html
<div class="circle" [ngStyle]="changeBackground()">
    <!-- <content></content> --> <!-- content is now deprecated -->
    <ng-content><ng-content> <!-- Use ng-content instead -->
</div>
```

**The shortest way is probably like this:**

```html
<div class="circle" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': color }">
    <!-- <content></content> --> <!-- content is now deprecated -->
    <ng-content><ng-content> <!-- Use ng-content instead -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 25):

I managed to make it work with alpha28 like this:

```js
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'circle', 
  properties: ['color: color'],
})
@View({
    template: `<style>
    .circle{
        width:50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
</style>
<div class="circle" [style.background-color]="changeBackground()">
    <content></content>
</div>
`
})
export class Circle {
    color;

    constructor(){
    }

    changeBackground(): string {
        return this.color;
    }
}
```

and called it like this `<circle color='yellow'></circle>`

Answer (score 7):

- In your **app.component.html** use:

  ```
    [ngStyle]="{'background-color':backcolor}"
  ```
- In **app.ts** declare variable of string type `backcolor:string`.
- Set the variable `this.backcolor="red"`.

Answer (score 6):

This works fine in Angular 11 and possibly earlier:

```
<div [style.backgroundColor]="myBgColor" [style.color]="myColor">Jesus loves you</div>
```

And in controller .ts file:

```
myBgColor = '#1A1A1A'
myColor = '#FFFFFF'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `[attr.style]="changeBackground()"`

Comment: Avoid calling method in ts file for all angular bindings, *ngFor *ngIf and so on. Add a console.log('ping') in that method an look at tha mount of hits.