# Angular interpolation using "ngIf"

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a table in which I want the first column to take a specific color according to a variable in my class. For example, I have a class DisplayProject.ts which has an attribute called `indexOfColor`

***DisplayProject.ts***

```
export class DispalyProject implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  project: Project;
  indexOfColor: number = 1; // can be 2 

  constructor () {
  }
}
```

***DisplayProject.html***

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>the project name</th>
      <th>the project date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>project.name</td>
      <td>project.date</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the column "the project name" to be green if `indexOfColor = 1` and be blue if `indexOfColor = 2`

***Any solutions ?***

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to implement specific styles based on variables.

```
<th [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': indexOfColor == 1 ? 'green' : 'blue' }">
  the project name
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Component:

```
@Component({ selector: 'app-comp', ... })
export class DispalyProject {
  @Input() public project: Project;
  @Input() public indexOfColor: 1 | 2 = 1; //can be 2
}
```

SCSS stylesheet:

```
.default-color {
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

Template:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="default-color" [ngClass]="{ blue: indexOfColor === 2 }">
       the project name
     </th>
     <th>
       the project date
     </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>project.name</td>
     <td>project.date</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class you can do:

SCSS

```
.color-green {
  color: green;
}

.color-blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

Template:

```
<th [ngClass]="{
    'color-green': indexOfColor === 1
    'color-blue': indexOfColor === 2
    }">
    the project name
</th>
```

In this case if one day you want to add another condition, you just have to add one line

Answer (score 0):

```
<th [style.background]="{ indexOfColor == 1 ? 'green' : {indexOfColor == 2 ? 'blue' :'black'}">
</th>
```

Reference from [Binding value to style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515475/binding-value-to-style)