# bottom navigation bar nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, bottomnavigationview, angular2-nativescript

In the bottom navigation bar  I want to change the button ActiveColor when I get true from service but the problem is I can't override button color with CSS it doesn't apply(nativescript angular)

```
<MDBottomNavigation....>
<MDTabStrip>
 <MDTabStripItem>
  ....
  <Image src="font..." [ngClass]="actionsActive?'first-color':'second-color'">
 ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried dynamically adding a new class with javascript. Something like this:

```
element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

and

your css file you can add:

```
.mystyle:active {
  background-color: some
}
```

Also you can use a variable like this:

```
[style.backgroundColor]="myBgColor"
```

and than dynamically set value to myBgColor

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515475/binding-value-to-style)

Comment: nativescript angular?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean bottom navigation bar in nativescript angular doesn't change color of  MDTabStripItem Image in mobile application